# Is it alright that the nvidia drivers from PPA depend on xserver-xorg-core?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-410 : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 (= 410.78-0ubuntu1~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Recursively digging into depended packages (starting from xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-xxx for me), it finally ends in xserver-xorg-core. But I don't feel like any of the packages of that group is needed at all.

This is a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation, nothing was done to the system except adding the graphics-drivers PPA. Neither of `apt install -f`, `apt install --fix-broken`, `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` spotted any mistakes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is alright.

`xserver-xorg-core` is the service to render your desktop.
`xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410` will provide optimized hardware acceleration for your X Server.

X Server is pre-installed under Ubuntu, if you look at the [default packages](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.2/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest) of Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: Sounds fair, but why doesn't the same happen if I install the latest driver given by the official repo (nvidia-390 currently, and to avoid the same dependency message, I need to install nvidia-driver-390)?

Comment: Seems the graphics-drivers PPA was not up to date for the new hwe kernel. It got fixed some hours ago, try apt update and nvidia-driver-410 again. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1815579

Comment: Not only [390](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/411431101/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2.diff.gz) as in the bug report, but also [410](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/411431119/nvidia-graphics-drivers-410_410.78-0ubuntu1~gpu18.04.1_410.78-0ubuntu1~gpu18.04.2.diff.gz) and [415](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/411431129/nvidia-graphics-drivers-415_415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2.diff.gz) were fixed.

Comment: This is NOT OK! As of writing, installing `xserver-xorg-core` directly will remove `ubuntu-desktop`, `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04`, and every other graphics package and give you a permanent black screen after logging in.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely NOT alright. It's dangerous.

Installing `xserver-xorg-core` requires `ubuntu-desktop`, `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04`, and basically every other essential graphics package to be removed. The consequence would be a permanent black screen. I encountered the same problem while installing CUDA 10.1.

I found a solution: use the `graphics-drivers` ppa version of `nvidia-driver-418` instead of the default one. This version does not depend on `xserver-xorg-core` and should not cause a black screen. Do the following (after a reboot):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-418
```

After a reboot, you should be able to use `nvidia-smi` and follow the original CUDA 10.1 .deb (local) instructions if you are also installing CUDA.

Comment: This answer helped me install cuda. Otherwise, `apt` will fail trying to install a dependency: `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410`